# How to get the group that has the MAX value for the grouped column

Tags: sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table KIDS that have a Column AGE.
I want to use an SQL query to get all the records of the oldest kids.

For example: If I have

```
Name   Age
----------
David   10 
Dan     10
Leah     8 
Hannah   6
```

I want to get David's and Dan's records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select * from tablename
where age in (select max(age) from tablename)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `max()`

```
  select * from t where age = (select max(age) from t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the below code:

```
select * from old_Records where age =(select max(age) from old_Records)
```